# Magento 2 - Authorize.net Error Codes

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2,

When a customer checks out using a credit card, Authorize.net, and the payment fails due to address verification, or any other reason, all Magento says is "Server error. Please contact administrator".

In Magento 1, there was an extension that could be installed that would give the customer the proper error message i.e. payment failed to payment AVS Address Failure.

Is there anything like this for Magento 2?

Comment: As you mentioned there was an extension for Magento Ver 1, you can try to replicate it in Magento Ver 2 and make it available for others as well or make a git repo so that others can also contribute. Otherwise plz share what you tried.

Comment: I wish I knew how to do that - but Im not that good at Magento yet. Im thinking about just editing the phtml file that contains the authorize.net error codes, but im not sure which one that is.